# Send Parameter HttpWebRequest return XML

Tags: c#, post, parameters, send, httpwebresponse

Good morning,

I am trying to connect to a payment gateway which sends you a post parameters using HttpWebRequest.

The code that has done in the api is php but I need in C#.

```
function send_trans($url, $postData) {
$headers = array( 'Connection: Keep-Alive',
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko
/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 40); // timeout en 40 segundos
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$xml = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return ($xml);
}
```

have tried it with the following code.

```
public static string HttpPostRequest (string url, Dictionary <string, string> postParameters)
        {
            string postData = "";

            foreach (string key in postParameters.Keys)
            {
                postData + = key + "=" + postParameters [key] + "&";
            }

            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create (url);
            myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            byte [] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes (postData);

            myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application / x-www-form-urlencoded";
            myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

            Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream ();
            requestStream.Write (data, 0, data.Length);
            requestStream.Close ();

            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse ();

            Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream ();

            StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader (responseStream, Encoding.Default);

            string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd ();

            myStreamReader.Close ();
            responseStream.Close ();

            myHttpWebResponse.Close ();

            return pageContent;
        }
```

the error it gives me is in the line of Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream (), I have tried with other code and it is always the same error in GetResponseStream.

Comment: `the error it gives me is in the line of Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream (), I have tried with other code and it is always the same error in GetResponseStream.` What error does it give you?

Comment: did u try with postman. first try from postman then take code in c#. By the way what is the error it gives

Comment: give me the error that is "Connection terminated: Unexpected sending error."